# 'content' cannot be specified for Article model form as it is a non-editable field

Tags: python, django, django-cms, divio

I am currently upgrading a Django 1.9 site to use Django 1.10. I would love to upgrade to Django 1.11, but some of the packages the site uses do not yet support it.

Either way, I am getting the following error when I go to `localhost:8000`

> FieldError at /
>
> 'content' cannot be specified for Article model form as it is a
>   non-editable field
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/ Django
>   Version:  1.10.9 Exception Type:  FieldError Exception Value:
>
> 'content' cannot be specified for Article model form as it is a
>   non-editable field
>
> Exception Location:
>     /xxx-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in
>   fields_for_model, line 143

The site is running Django CMS 3.4.4, as well as other Aldryn Plugins, all of which are up-to-date using `pip install`.

The code in question is this:

```
    if (fields is not None and f.name in fields and
            (exclude is None or f.name not in exclude)):
        raise FieldError(
            "'%s' cannot be specified for %s model form as it is a non-editable field" % (
                f.name, model.__name__)
        )
    continue
```

I would love some tips or directions on how I could troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome the bug by installing the latest master version of `aldryn-newsblog` with:
`pip install git+https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog.git@master`

You may also watch the discussion from [here](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog/issues/444) or [here](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog/issues/440).